# Clicking on Recyclerview item has a late item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, mutablelivedata

I have an application using databinding, livedata, room, kotlin koroutines, viewmodel, retrofit and koin. I have one activity, and two fragments.

UserListFragment: Show in a recyclerview a list of user items.

UserFullProfileFragment: Show the user item detail.

When the application is running, an external API is called to retrieve a list of users and display it in a recyclerview. Then, if I click on one item, an external API is called to get the detail of the current user whith its ID.
The problem is when I click on one item at the first, everything is going well but for following items, this is the detail of previous item which is displayed and so on and so forth.

Any ideas ?

UserRepository:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl (private val userApi: UserApi, private val userDao: UserDao, private val networkStateManager: NetworkStateManager) : UserRepository {

override suspend fun getUserList(): Result<List<UserListItem>> {
    if (networkStateManager.hasNetWorkConnection()) {
        return try {
            // get user list from user API
            val response = userApi.getUserList()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("REPO", "get users from api")
                response.body()?.let { userResponse ->
                    Log.d("REPO", "response:$response")
                    val userList = userResponse.data
                    // convert user API object to user entity
                    val entities = userList.map { it.toUserEntity() }
                    // save user list in database
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { userDao.addUsers(entities) }

                    // convert user entity to user model
                    val userItemList = entities.map { it.toUserListItem() }

                    return Result.Success(userItemList)
                } ?: handleFailure(response)
            } else {
                handleFailure(response)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return Result.Failure(e, e.localizedMessage)
        }
    } else {
        // get user list from database if no network
        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { userDao.findAllUsers() }
        return if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d("REPO", "get users from db")
            val userItemList = data.map { it.toUserListItem() }
            Result.Success(userItemList)
        } else {
            Result.Failure(Exception("error"), "no network connection")
        }
    }
}

override suspend fun getUserFullProfile(userId: String): Result<UserFullProfile> {
    if (networkStateManager.hasNetWorkConnection()) {
        return try {
            // get user from user API
            val response = userApi.getUserFullProfile(userId)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("REPO", "get users from api")
                response.body()?.let { userResponse ->
                    Log.d("REPO", "response:$userResponse")

                    // convert user API object to user entity
                    val userEntity = userResponse.toUserEntity()
                    // save user data in database
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { userDao.addUserFullProfile(userEntity) }

                    // convert user entity to user model
                    val user = userEntity.toUserFullProfile()

                    return Result.Success(user)
                } ?: handleFailure(response)
            } else {
                handleFailure(response)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return Result.Failure(e, e.localizedMessage)
        }
    } else {
        // get user from database if no network
        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { userDao.getUserById(userId) }
        return if (data != null) {
            Log.d("REPO", "get users from db")
            val user = data.toUserFullProfile()
            Result.Success(user)
        } else {
            Result.Failure(Exception("error"), "no network connection")
        }
    }
}
```

UserViewModel:
getUserList and getUserFullProfile are use cases which call the repository

```
class UserViewModel (private val getUserList: GetUserList, private val getUserFullProfile: GetUserFullProfile) : ViewModel() {

val userList = MutableLiveData<List<UserListItem>>()
val userFullProfile = MutableLiveData<UserFullProfile>()

fun getUserList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        when (val result = getUserList.getUserList()) {
            is Result.Success -> userList.value = result.successData
            is Result.Failure -> result.exception.localizedMessage
        }
    }
}

fun getUserFullProfile(userId: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        when (val result = getUserFullProfile.getUserFullProfile(userId)) {
            is Result.Success -> userFullProfile.value = result.successData
            is Result.Failure -> result.exception.localizedMessage
        }
    }
}
```

UserRecyclerAdaper:

```
class UserRecyclerAdapter(private val context: Context?, val clickListener: UserClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRecyclerAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

var userList : List<UserListItem> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
    val inflatedView: UserItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.user_item, parent, false)
    return UserViewHolder(inflatedView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindUser(position)
}

override fun getItemCount() = userList.size

fun setUsers(users: List<UserListItem>) {
    this.userList = users
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

inner class UserViewHolder(private val v: UserItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v.root) {

    fun bindUser(position: Int) {
        val item = userList[position]
        Log.d("ADAPTER", item.toString())
        v.user = item
        Picasso.get()
            .load(item.picture)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .into(v.picture)
        v.userClickInterface = clickListener

        v.root.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClick(item)
        }
    }
}
```

UserListFragment:

```
class UserListFragment : Fragment(), UserClickListener {
private val userViewModel by viewModel<UserViewModel>()
private lateinit var userAdapter: UserRecyclerAdapter
private lateinit var viewDataBinding: FragmentUserListBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false)
    viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
    return viewDataBinding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    userAdapter = UserRecyclerAdapter(context, this)
    recyclerView.adapter = userAdapter
    recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false

    viewDataBinding.viewModel = userViewModel

    userViewModel.getUserList()
    userViewModel.userList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { userList ->
        if (userList.isNotEmpty() && userList != null) {
            userAdapter.setUsers(userList)
        }
    })
}

override fun onItemClick(user: UserListItem) {
    Log.d("FRAGMENT", user.toString())
    userViewModel.getUserFullProfile(user.id)
    userViewModel.userFullProfile.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { userFullProfile ->
        Log.d("UFP", userFullProfile.toString())
        if (userFullProfile !=  null) {
            (activity as MainActivity).replaceFragment(UserFullProfileFragment.newInstance(userFullProfile),
                R.id.fragment_layout, "userFullProfile")
        }
    })
}
```

UserFullProfileFragment:

```
class UserFullProfileFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(user: UserFullProfile) = UserFullProfileFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putParcelable("user", user)
        }
    }
}

private var user: UserFullProfile? = null
private lateinit var mViewDataBinding: FragmentUserFullProfileBinding

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mViewDataBinding.user = user
    notify()
    Picasso.get()
        .load(mViewDataBinding.user?.picture)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .into(mViewDataBinding.picture)

    val dateOfBirth = parseDate(mViewDataBinding.user?.dateOfBirth)
    mViewDataBinding.dateOfBirth.text = dateOfBirth

    val registerDate = parseDate(mViewDataBinding.user?.registerDate)
    mViewDataBinding.registerDate.text = registerDate
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    user = arguments?.getParcelable("user")
    Log.d("APP", user.toString())
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    mViewDataBinding  = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_user_full_profile, container, false)
    mViewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
    return mViewDataBinding.root
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: please attach the recycler view images

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution :
I pass the user id argment from UserListFragment to UserFullProfileFragment instead of the current user object and I call the external API to get the current user in the UserFullProfileFragment.

This is the final code:

UserListFragment:

```
override fun onItemClick(user: UserListItem) {
    val action = UserListFragmentDirections.actionUserListFragmentToUserFullProfileFragment(user.id)
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

UserFullProfileFragment:

```
class UserFullProfileFragment  : Fragment() {

private lateinit var userID: String
private var mViewDataBinding: FragmentUserFullProfileBinding? = null
private val binding get() = mViewDataBinding!!
private val userViewModel by viewModel<UserViewModel>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.viewModel = userViewModel
    userID = UserFullProfileFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).userArgs
    userViewModel.getUserFullProfile(userID)
    userViewModel.userFullProfile.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { userFullProfile ->
        if (userFullProfile !=  null) {
            binding.user = userFullProfile
            Picasso.get()
                .load(binding.user?.picture)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(binding.picture)

            val dateOfBirth = parseDate(binding.user?.dateOfBirth)
            binding.dateOfBirth.text = dateOfBirth

            val registerDate = parseDate(binding.user?.registerDate)
            binding.registerDate.text = registerDate
        }
    })

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    mViewDataBinding  = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_user_full_profile, container, false)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    mViewDataBinding = null
}
```

}